# Is there an effective way to secure access to my API from Salesforce?

Tags: api, salesforce, api-key

I have built an API to my web application so that customers can access certain functionality without going through the dashboard. I have secured it by providing an API key to each customer that identifies them and restricts the IP address from which they can connect.

I have now had a request from a customer to allow them to access this API from their Salesforce platform. I don't know much about Salesforce, and when I asked them to let me know their IP address so I could create their API key, all they could give me was the list of reserved IP addresses published by Salesforce. This IP space is huge (millions), covering all of Salesforce, meaning that if someone gained access to the API key they'd be able to use it from any Salesforce account.

I have read some things about Salesforce having an OAuth service and having some kind of Application Connect service, but it mostly seems to be designed around allowing 3rd parties to connect to Salesforce - I'm getting a bit bogged down trying to determine if this is any use in my scenario (which requires authentication in the other direction).

I'd be grateful for any insight into whether there's something more specific I can do identify a particular Salesforce customer beyond simply putting dozens of CIDR blocks in my API key. I could ask my customer to identify themselves in the referer header when they call my API, for example, but of course that's trivial to spoof.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[IPs can be spoofed too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing)

Salesforce has a concept of ["protected custom settings"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cs_schema_settings.htm&type=5). You could make a "managed package" (Salesforce plugin, but you don't need to distribute it on their appexchange, Google Play/App Store equivalent), install it for the client and then enter the API key to the setting in a way that even client's sysadmins can't read it.
It'd be bit of work to set it up but might pay off if you think you'll get more customers on the platform.

How about a crude but effective iframe? or a link to your page they'd embed somewhere in their app?

Do you have just api keys? If you'd expose OAuth2 endpoint SF users could login to your app and then SF code could use access_token they got back instead of api keys. Or maybe you can protect access with certificate? Calling app would have to sign requests with a certificate. Client could upload it to their SF, you'd upload to your app...

You could demand the API calls to include the user's SF "session id" and you could use that to run some queries against source SF org. Org Id, user's login history etc things that are impossible to tweak even by sysadmins...

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I'm not really anticipating any further SF customers, and I do already have an iframe to expose 1 particular page, but this requirement is for the full platform API. I looked into using the SF Session ID as that seemed promising, but I couldn't find any concrete examples of how I could use that without having an SF account myself. I guess for now I'll just carry on with full SF IP Network encrypted in a bearer token and maybe revisit this another time.

Comment: You can sign up for free Developer Edition and experiment (all toys, limited storage space) or the customer could create an user for you in their test (sandbox) environment. Sounds like you found least effort solution though